# Branch cuts without intersection

Tags: complex-analysis

Branch cuts are related with branch points. And normally branch cuts end at branch points or infinity. Branch cuts are not unique for a system, that means we can find different ways to define branch cuts. For example, the figure below shows two possible ways of plotting branch cuts. There is an intersection between branch cuts in the left, and no intersection in the right.

My question is that Is there always a way to plot the branch cuts without intersections? It seems this statement is correct, but is there any reference having this statement(or show this is wrong)? Since I am writing a paper and I need to convince people this is correct.

[image]

Comment: I hope you're not thinking that branch cuts always have to be straight lines.

Comment: Yes, I know branch cuts can be curves. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Try induction. Show that if you can draw $n$ branch cuts without intersection, then you can always slip in one more.

Comment: You might be interested in Example 1 in Section 2.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.7223.pdf

Comment: Any thoughts, Qi?

Comment: Thank you, @GerryMyerson. This paper is useful and I am also trying to read the references it listed.